# xcode json tableview sections

Tags: json, header, xcode4, tableview

I am new to xcode and I seem to be stuck at trying to create a tableview with sections.

My code below creates the header however I cannot seem to display the rows that belong to the section. I'm sure it has to do with the multidimensional array. I say this because "dobSection" value is "results" when I suppose it should display the dates under "DOB".

I have spent hours trying many different ways to get this to work..... eh! No luck.

The Json is somewhat like this:

```
{"results":
    [{"name":"joe","surname":"blow","DOB":"1990-01-01"},
     {"name":"jane","surname":"doe","DOB":"1990-01-01"},
     {"name":"john","surname":"doe","DOB":"1995-06-06"}]
}
```

and the code

```
NSMutableArray *jsonResults;

- (void)fetchedData:(NSData *)responseData {

NSError* error;

NSDictionary* json = [NSJSONSerialization

                      JSONObjectWithData:responseData

                      options:kNilOptions

                      error:&error];

jsonResults = [json objectForKey:@"results"];


self.dob = json;

self.keys = [jsonResults valueForKey:@"DOB"];

[self.tableView reloadData];

}


- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView

{

    // Return the number of sections.
    return [keys count];
    //return 1;

}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section

{

    // Return the number of rows in the section.
   // NSString *key = [keys objectAtIndex:section];

   NSString *key = [keys objectAtIndex:section];

   NSArray *dobSection = [dob objectForKey:key];
   return [dobSection count];
}
```

in addition by replacing this:

```
NSArray *dobSection = [dob objectForKey:key];
```

with

```
NSArray *dobSection=[[games objectForKey:@"results"]valueForKey:@"dob"];
```

I get all rows.
I cannot get them to group by DOB

My code above may be flawed however I would love some input on how to get this right.

Thank you

Comment: what should `self.keys` store after `self.keys = [jsonResults valueForKey:@"DOB"];` ?

Comment: "keys" only represents the value of the section headers for the table. I dont use "keys" again